# Creating a HUD (scale invariant text / labels) in SVG/Raphael when using setViewBox

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am creating Raphael web app to allow panning and zooming a floor plan.  This all works great but I cannot seem to find out how I can add scale invariant text (or other objects) onto the interface.  Everything scales and moves when a user pans / zooms.  I basically want HUD features to remain in their positions / sizes in spite of any user panning / zooming.

I currently zoom / pan using `setViewBox`

```
paper.setViewBox(x,y,newViewBoxWidth,newViewBoxHeight);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UI should be in a separate Raphael paper laid on top of your floorplan.

Plain SVG allows nesting SVGs but Raphael doesn't, as it must provide VML fallbacks.

Comment: Thanks, I came to this conclusion myself a short while ago